# This.state.someThing in array count

Tags: react-native

I have state and i want this use in array count, but i can not do it. I use react-navigation. Maybe you know another example.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      whileI: this.props.navigation.getParam('i'),
      count: this.props.navigation.getParam('count'),
      countTrue: 0,
    }
  }
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: (
        <View style={{height: "10%", backgroundColor: '#1194F6', elevation: 5, justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          {Array.from(Array(this.state.count).keys()).map(idx => (
            <View key={idx} style={{ flex: 1,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: '#767', 
              marginLeft: 2,
              marginTop: "8%",
              marginRight: 2,
              marginBottom: 5,
              backgroundColor: '#C5C5C5',
              backgroundColor: '#F8F',
            }}></View>
          ))}
        </View>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can try to get values from navigation params, so your navigationOptions can be overridden as a function. Here is an example how to do this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html

Also, another way to do this - use some HOC to pass your data as a props to screen component(or use context api or redux). It depends on your needs.